# Excel VBA: Find the maximum value in each row and highlight it

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to VBA. Right now I am trying to do these two things for me: 1. find the maximum value in each **row**. 2. Highlight the maximum value found in yellow. Do these until row empty.
In each row, cells may or may not contain value.

I tried to use conditional formatting to help me solve my problem. But it does not seem to work.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you know anything about nested loops and how to code in VBA? I'd gladly point you in the right direction, but if that is your first time using VBA, you might want to start with a tutorial, rather than asking for someone to accomplish the task at hand for you.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.  Questions which do not contain any code, and which are asking for a code solution should be removed...

Comment: Conditional formatting to highlight max value on row: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/highlight-the-lowest-and-highest-value-in-an-excel-row-or-column/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I was looking for a VBA code. it works perfect for me with this conditional formatting method.

Comment: David, I have some code written down, did not know we have to put code here in order to ask questions. But thank you for your advise, I will keep in mind for my next question.

Comment: Bernard, Thank you for your advise. I did watch some tutorials.I am taking baby steps to learn this. Next time I will put my code here for my question.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub HiLighter()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Dim rA As Range, r, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim V As Variant, RWW As Range, rr As Range
    Set rA = Intersect(Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each r In rA
        Set RWW = Intersect(r.EntireRow, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If wf.CountA(RWW) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        V = wf.Max(RWW)
        For Each rr In RWW
            If rr.Value = V Then
                rr.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                GoTo getaway
            End If
        Next rr
getaway:
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Gary's Student for your kindness help. I will give it a try.